# How to interpret these distributions?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation

I'm analysing some stack overflow data and trying to characterise four variables with appropriate distributions.

The histograms below show each variable untransformed. The common theme is that the vast majority of the values are approximately 1-5 (except for with `question_score`) but that there are some extreme – but valid - outliers.

I have assessed the outliers via detailed percentile analysis. Unfortunately they are too few in number to have a meaningful visual impact in the plots below. However, the automatic setting of the x-axis's helps here in that it points to their presence.

[image: Non-Logged]

Below are the breakdowns of the mean, variance and standard deviation.

```
question_score: mean = 1 | variance = 7 | std = 2.68
views: mean = 145 | variance = 49008 | std = 221.37
answers: mean = 3 | variance = 8 | std = 2.97
answer_score: mean = 5 | variance = 270 | std = 16.44
```

Re-plotting the data using a log transform is much more informative.

[image: Logged]

Of the four variables, I'm most interested in characterising `question_score` and `views` as I would like to attempt to the model their relationship.

I understand that the data are discrete and have spent hours working through this link [Distributions List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions#Supported_on_semi-infinite_intervals.2C_usually_.5B0.2C.E2.88.9E.29) to better understand these distributions, but to no avail.

I would be really grateful is someone can offer some guidance as to how I should interpret these two distributions before attempting to model them.

Comment: Why do you want to assume some parametric form?  To simplify regression modelling?

Comment: @generic_user Exactly.

Comment: The best way to characterize `question_score` would be to break it into a difference of upvotes and downvotes.  Model those two counts separately.

Comment: @whuber If I were to split and model the counts in this way, what type of model would you suggest? A Poisson GLM perhaps?

Comment: That would be a good point of departure.